# Spring Constructor Injection throws error

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Spring application i tried setter injection it worked well. when i write constructor injection it fails.

```
public class Sample {

    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public Sample(){

    }

    public Sample(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate){
        System.out.println("invoked");
        this.jdbcTemplate=jdbcTemplate;
    }
}
```

context file

```
<bean id="derbyDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />
    <property name="url"
        value="jdbc:derby:#{systemProperties['user.appdata']}/${db.name};create=true" />
    <property name="username" value="${db.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
</bean>



<!-- JDBC Template Bean -->
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
     <property name="dataSource" ref="derbyDataSource" />
</bean>



<bean id="sample" class="com.exbury.Sample">
    <constructor-arg ref="jdbcTemplate"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Load context

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("derbyDatabaseConfiguration.xml");
```

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer$ParameterNameDiscoveringVisitor has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
```

Comment: this is why I don't like spring

Comment: Can you try recompile the project?

Comment: tried several times. but doesn't work.

Comment: when i remove the bean mentioned above. it is working.

Answer (score 0):

This [Source](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-asm-dependency-issue-in-spring-data/) solves similar error. I am not sure about your's but can you try adding this exclusion?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>your version</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```